# How can I use wildcards in my gcp bucket objects path?

Tags: object, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket

My main problem is,
I want to check if an object in gcp exists or not. So, what I tried

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
path_exists = False
for blob in client.list_blobs('models', prefix='trainedModels/mddeep256_sarim'):
    path_exists = True
    break
```

It worked fine for me.
But now the problem is I don't know the model name which is **mddeep256** but I know further part **_sarim**

So, I want to use something like

```
for blob in client.list_blobs('models', prefix='trainedModels/*_sarim'):
```

I want to use * wildcard, how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list_blob` doesn't support regex in `prefix`. you need filter by yourself as mentioned by Guilaume.

following should work.

```py
def is_object_exist(bucket_name, object_pattern):
    from google.cloud import storage
    import re
    client = storage.Client()
    all_blobs = client.list_blobs(bucket_name)
    regex = re.compile(r'{}'.format(object_pattern))
    filtered_blobs = [b for b in all_blobs if regex.match(b.name)]
    return True if len(filtered_blobs) else False
```

Answer (score 2):

In short: you can't!

You can only filter on the prefix. If you want to filter on the suffix (as you wish), start by filter on the longest prefix that you can with the API, and then iterate in your code to scan the file name and get those that match your pattern.

No built-il solution for that...