# Python code not working in google cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to move three month old files from one bucket to another bucket using python code. I tested the code using `test function()` in cloud function, it doesn't throw any error and status message shown as `'ok'`.

In source bucket, my files located in `gs://source_bucket_name/history/subfolder1/filename, gs://source_bucket-name/history/subfolder2/filename, etc.,` from here I want to move my files to destination bucket. I tried to achieve this using below python code but it's not working.

```
from google.cloud import storage
import zipfile
import datetime
import os

def move_files(request, context):
    source_bucket_name = 'source_bucket_name'
    destination_bucket_name = 'destination_bucket_name'
    client = storage.Client()

    source_bucket = client.get_bucket(source_bucket_name)
    destination_bucket = client.get_bucket(destination_bucket_name)

    three_month_file = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=90)
    
    prefixes = ['history/*/DATA_*', 'history/*/CTRL_*']

    for prefix in prefixes:
        for blob in source_bucket.list_blobs(prefix=prefix):
            blob_updated = blob.updated
            if blob_updated < three_month_file:
                #Create temporary local directory to store the zipped file
                temp_dir = 'temp'
                os.makedirs(temp_dir,exist_ok=True)

                #Download the file to the temporary local directory
                blob.download_to_filename(os.path.join(temp_dir,blob.name))
               

                #Zip the file
                zip_Name = os.path.join(temp_dir,f"{blob.name}.zip")
                with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_Name,'w') as zipfile_obj:
                    zipfile_obj.write(os.path.join(temp_dir,blob.name),blob.name)
                  

                #move the zipeed file to destination bucket
                destination_blob = destination_bucket.blob(f"{blob.name}.zip")
                destination_blob.upload_files(zip_Name)

                #Delete the original file and zipped file
                os.remove(os.path.join(temp_dir,blob.name))
                os.remove(zip_Name)

                #Delete the original from the source bucket
                blob.delete()
            #Remove the temporary local directory
    os.rmdir(temp_dir)
    print("successful")
```

I have no any idea why it's failing. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: What do you mean "not working"?

Comment: files are not moving to the destination bucket. It's still remains in the source bucket

Comment: Suggestion: Cloud Storage supports bucket-to-bucket object copies. Your code is download-upload.

Comment: please provide the error handling if any

Comment: note that downloading a file and then uploading file is a "copy" not a "move", so of course you will still see files remain in the source bucket. The question is, do you see the files in the target bucket?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: I don't see the files in target bucket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From @John Hanley's suggestion, cloud storage indeed supports bucket-to-bucket object copies, which are more efficient than the method of downloading and uploading files.

For example:

```
for prefix in prefixes:
    for blob in source_bucket.list_blobs(prefix=prefix):
        blob_updated = blob.updated
        if blob_updated < three_month_file:
            destination_blob = destination_bucket.blob(blob.name)

            # Copy the object to the destination bucket
            source_bucket.copy_blob(blob, destination_bucket, destination_blob.name)

            # Delete the original object from the source bucket
            blob.delete()

print("Successful")
```

With this function, it will perform a bucket-to-bucket object copy directly within Cloud Storage which can be more effecient and faster for moving objects between buckets.

For further information and references, you can explore the following links:

**[Python copy blob](https://www.programcreek.com/python/?CodeExample=copy%20blob)**

**[How to move or copy Azure Blob from one container to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500935/python-how-to-move-or-copy-azure-blob-from-one-container-to-another)**

---

**Updated answer**

Yes the issue might be related to your use of asterisk. You can try using the delimiter parameter. Or visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71493905/how-can-i-use-wildcards-in-my-gcp-bucket-objects-path)

Comment: My code not entering inside the for loop  - `for blob in source_bucket.list_blobs(prefix=prefix): ` . Is that because of the `*` used in the prefixes?